# Multiple .ghci Files

Tags: macos, haskell, ghci

I have a .ghci file with configurations for a Haskell project in the directory Project. When I run ghci from the Mac terminal in the directory Project, ghci loads both the project's Project/.ghci file and the home directory ~/.ghci file. Is there a method to prevent the ~./ghci configurations from being loaded or have the Project/.ghci overwrite the ~./ghci configurations?

Comment: The project's `.ghci` *should* override the global one. Could you give an example of configurations that don't act how you expect?

Comment: the :set prompt in Project/.ghci doesn't override the :set prompt in ~/.ghci

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this isn't how `ghci` works according to [the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-ghci-and-haskeline-files). It loads all `.ghci` files in order, starting with the one in the current directory, which is why your prompt is taking on the value in your root `.ghci` rather than the one in the project.

You may have a better experience removing the `.ghci` files and using `cabal new-build` and `cabal new-repl`, assuming your project is Cabalized. This doesn't give you an option to set the prompt, but if that's an important element then you could always retain the `.ghci` at the project level and remove the global one. You'll still be able to specify available modules and extensions, though.

Comment: From the link, this information might be useful: "Additionally, any files specified with `-ghci-script` flags will be read after the standard files, allowing the use of custom .ghci files."